# Table Row... Show an alert onClick

Tags: html, onclick

Hello I have a simple HTML table with several rows. I want to alert the user with a message when they click on a particular row. Here is what I tried to get this to work...

```
        <tr onClick="alert(some Message)">
            <td>${o.hospitalId}</td>

            <td>${o.name}</td>

            <td>${o.address}</td>
        </tr>
```

However, that is not working. Am I missing some HTML basics here?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be ok, but try:

`<tr onclick="javascript:alert('something');">`

or try [jquery](http://jquery.com):

`$("tr").click(function () { alert("something"); });`

Comment: <table>
<tr>
   <td onclick="alert('You are clicking on the cell EXAMPLE')"> Data </td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1):

Code seems to be good, of course if you want display literary 'some Message' text it must be between ' and ', like in lante's example. If it won't work still, you can have javascript disabled in browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

add these 'some message' and then it will work fine

```
    <tr onClick="alert('some Message')">

        <td>${o.hospitalId}</td>
        <td>${o.name}</td>
        <td>${o.address}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Ideally, your answer should explain why this code will help.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Message** should be single quotes ' text ' reason behind your alert not working

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td onclick="alert('You are clicking on the cell EXAMPLE')"> Data </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```